# Is it possible to add to a Unity project (built for WebGL) an embedded in-app web browser?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

The motivation is to allow the user not to leave the app when pressing a link and opening it as an embedded window.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Unity as a library](https://blogs.unity3d.com/ru/2019/06/17/add-features-powered-by-unity-to-native-mobile-apps/) in native apps

Comment: is there a unity development based solution? if the app is developed by unity as well?

Comment: They have sample [Android](https://forum.unity.com/threads/integration-unity-as-a-library-in-native-android-app.685240/) and [iOS](https://forum.unity.com/threads/integration-unity-as-a-library-in-native-ios-app.685219/) projects